# Spring config client configuration not updated with "/actuator/refresh" endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I am using Spring 2.0.3. Database configuration of config client are getting from git repository via config server.

I have changed database configuration and push back into the git.

Then, I have called to "http://client_host/actuator/refresh" endpoint for load new configuration.

I have already exposed the "refresh" endpoint in my application.yml file. 
The results are,
Config server call to git repository and can manged to save new configuration in  "/tmp/repos".

However config client couldn't update database configuration?

Could you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://client_host/actuator/refresh" will only update the static configurations where as /actuator/bus-refresh or /bus/refresh will update all the dynamic configurations and it will trigger all the cloud client to refresh their instances.